# Calculating the mAP from scores obtained in Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am actually working on a server where I run the Tensorflow OD API to train the model for my custom dataset. So, I divide my images into training, validation and test sets and run the train.py on training and validation sets. Next I run the inference using exported model checkpoint and frozen graph on my test images.
Now, my question is when I run the inference as provided in the example , I get an output dict with detection scores, number of detections, detection classes, detection masks etc for each image, so from these outputs how do I calculate the mAP for my test set?

Any guidance in this direction will be really helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use COCO's API for calculating COCO's metrics withing TF OD API. See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md#coco-api-installation).
TF feeds COCO's API with your detections and GT, and COCO API will compute COCO's metrics and return it the TF (thus you can display their progress for example in TensorBoard). mAP@0.5 is probably the metric which is most relevant (at it is the standard metric used for PASCAL VOC, Open Images, etc), while mAP@0.5:0.95 is a much more difficult one localization-wise.

Comment: Hey @netanel-sam, thanks for responding. So to use cocoapi, I will have to set metrics as coco in my eval config file and then make use of the cocoapi ?? Did I understand it properly? But then how do I input my tensorflow OD results into this coceval.py?

Comment: If you want to use the extended COCO metrics, yes. Once you install pycocotools and choose `metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"` TF handles the rest for you. In case you want, you can choose different metrics, as specified here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md